# scala self type can it really be compiled when using `extends`?

Tags: scala

I'm looking at [scala types of types self types annotation](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#self-type-annotation)

it says that `new Service` cannot be instantiated because of the usage of `self type` in favor of `extends`.  But I tried the example also with `extends` and it still does not compile.

```
class TryMe {
  class ServiceInModule {
    def doTheThings() = "dfdf"
  }
  trait Module {
    lazy val serviceInModule = new ServiceInModule
  }

  trait Service extends Module {
    def doTheThings() = serviceInModule.doTheThings()
  }

  trait TestingModule extends Module {

  }

  new Service
}
```

> Error:(22, 3) trait Service is abstract; cannot be instantiated   new
>   Service   ^

Am I missing something? why does it claim that with extends it should compile? it does not compile...

Comment: just do new Service {}

Comment: @EugeneZhulenev thanks can you please post this as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trait is like an enhances interface in java, it cannot be created directly. you need to subclass it, which is what you do by adding {}.

So you need to do

```
new Service {}
```

and you are creating not an instance of Service, but "anonymous class" that extends Service trait